# Which phrase sounds more correct

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I’ve got two sentences here using with or while

1. I’m feeling great this month while all my bills are paid in advance.
2. I’m feeling great this month with all my bills are paid in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only sentence one is grammatically correct.  To correct sentence two, remove "are":

> I'm feeling great this month, with all my bills paid in advance.

"With" is a preposition, so you don't need a verb after it.  On the contrary, "while" is a conjunction, so it needs a dependent clause after it, which contains a verb.
Another option I'd like to suggest is separating the two clauses with a semicolon:

> I'm feeling great this month; all my bills are paid in advance.

or separating them completely into two separate sentences:

> I'm feeling great this month.  All my bills are paid in advance!

or

> I'm feeling great this month. I paid all my bills in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is not right. The second is the better choice if you swap the two parts of the sentence:

**With all of my bills paid in advance, I'm feeling great about this month.**

If you keep it the way you had it, use "because" instead:

**I'm feeling great about this month because all of my bills are paid in advance.**

"While" means "even though" and signals that you're going to say something contrary to what's expected. For example:

**While all my bills are paid in advance. I'm still not feeling great about this month.**

Comment: "while" can also mean "for a specified duration," so the original sentence could mean something like: _I’m feeling great this month while all my bills are paid in advance. Next month, however, when the bills are due again, I'm going to be down in the dumps!_ (I agree with the general thrust of your answer, and I also agree my interpretation here is highly contextualized and somewhat awkward, but I just wanted to mention it for the sake of completeness.)

Comment: Good point. Thanks for the comment.